# Kill a running batch file from C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, kill-process

Is there a way to kill a batch process which is not started from C# code to kill from c# code. 
i.e. I have start.bat which is running and i want to kill it when a WPF app starts. Is this possible?? The WPF shall kill only start.at and not other batch running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From powershell I find the PID of Start.bat like this.

```
(gwmi win32_process | where {$_.commandline -match "START.BAT"} | select processID).processID
```

Invoke powershell from C# or just contact WMI directly, easy to find if you look at Win32_Process commandline and processID properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int processID = ... 
 // you also can use    Process.GetProcessesByName(....) to find the proicessID - or the batch process

 //Later when you need to kill the process...
 Process pToKill = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
 pToKill.Kill();
```

Comment: -1: the most interesting piece of magic is missing - one can easily find CMD.exe that runs that BAT/CMD file, but how you stop just the batch file, not its CMD?

Comment: Alexei how do i do that?

Comment: i dont have the process ID the process is started from outside the c# code.

Comment: @Khushi - if "start.bat" started interactively (by user typing "start.bat" in command prompt) one probably have to send Ctrl+C to correct CMD.exe (my guess, never done so). If "start.bat" started via `Process.Start` (or any other way that does start new CMD) than answer by Knuckle-Dragger (+1) is good starting point.